# Detecting Ramping Events for Wind Power Time Series in R

Tags: r, time-series, change-point

I'm working with a dataset that spits out a power generation reading from a wind turbine every 5 minutes. Because of the variability in wind speeds the plotted time series are very jumpy, with lots of movement up and down... I want to characterize all ramp events ( steep up or down movements in power production) above a certain threshold, like 40% increase or decrease of rated power over *x* amount of time, but I'm having trouble thinking through how to accomplish this. I would also like to be able to change the threshold to vary the sensitivity of what constitutes a ramp.

Here is an example time series from 2015:

[image: A Time Series of Christmas Day, 2015]

Comment: What does "characterize" mean in this context?

Comment: Know when they occur (date, time of day, which is also part of the dataset) and also whether they are an up or down ramping event.

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of seasonality? Eg, wind ramps up at dusk & ramps down at dawn? Or are you looking for a list of times when there were ramps?

Comment: Do they happen at predictable times? If so it can be modeled using time series analysis. If not you can use time series outlier detection techniques.

Comment: Looking at seasonality is an overarching goal, but I feel that will be straightforward after I'm able to characterize the ramps.

Comment: So really just a list of dates and times. I wouldn't say the ramping events occur at predictable times, but it really depends on how sensitive the characterization tool is. The issue is that the time series are unpredictable, so many different jumps and dips could be considered "outliers", making detection difficult.

Comment: @Randerson Please show a graph of a typical ramp.

Comment: What's the underlying research question that you're trying to answer? That will inform the choice of statistics

Comment: There are many different "accepted" definitions of a ramp event in the wind power series literature.  Once you have a definition it is simple to apply that to each time point and see if it fits or not.  This is not the way I would advocate doing it but in practice that is what is done.  In reality you probably want a stats method that detects the ramps and then compare the output to what is identified by the traditional definition.

Comment: @adunaic exactly. From the papers I have read, that is the by far the most common method for detecting ramps. I was hoping to improve on that practice as there are certainly flaws in just applying a definition to each point in the time series. I suppose that is what I will need to do, however.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I want to characterize the ramping events (seasonal and diurnal variability) to eventually look at the meteorological phenomena behind these steep increases and decreases in wind power production in order to enhance forecasting.

Comment: ah, ok, so you want to forecast steep ramp events. What sort of timescales? hour ahead, day ahead, week ahead, month ahead?

Comment: Hours to possibly days. Short range time scales, just long enough to alert a power grid operator of an upcoming ramping event.

Comment: ok. So are you after a scale, e.g. very-steep/short ramp versus medium-steep/longer ramp ? Or a simple yes/no? Or is there a scaling financial issue here, that varies with the steepness and length of the ramp?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a wonderful paper describing three methods to accomplish exactly what I am trying to do. 
http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/WAF-D-15-0144.1

It describes a fixed-time interval method, a minimum-maximum method, and an explicit derivative method, all of which are effective in characterizing ramps.

Comment: Good ref. Curious why you'd just want ramp events. Won't you want a full fledged prediction by hr?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out the breakout detection package? It is designed to test when the level of a time series goes through a shift that is "abnormal". Could be useful to tag events of interest, and if I'm not mistaken you can tune how sensitive you want it to be.
Here's a [link](https://github.com/twitter/BreakoutDetection).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I actually have used the breakout detection package. It works more on a mean-basis to show when the levels of a time series shift up or down. I'm looking more for a method to pick out sharp inclines/declines above a certain threshold and record them so that eventually their patterns can be detected, rather than just looking for when wind power level changes. Although recording information on the level changes could also be beneficial, so I'll spend more time with that package.

Comment: One method that's been handy is to simply look at a distribution of changes over time. When a change occurs that has been historically "rare" you could tag it. Over time you could evolve it.